# Setting up monitoring of ESXi HDDs with Kaseya Network Monitor

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esxi

I'm looking for some direction on how to setup monitoring for RAID and the physical HDDs in ESXi via KNM. Any link or advice would be of great help.

Comment: What hardware are you using - system, motherboard, RAID controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

http://blog.kaseya.com/blog/2012/03/23/how-to-monitor-vmware-using-kaseya-network-monitor-4-1/

You'll need the latest build of KNM 4.1, downloadable from:

http://www.kaseya.com/support/Downloads.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is a new release (Kaseya Network Monitor 4.1) available for download on the Kaseya download page that has both VMWare hardware monitoring via CIM / SMASH and performance monitoring via the VI API.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you have to monitor your ESXi from other server, not ESXi itself, as it is minited environment. There are couple of VMWare APIs you can use to query ESXi data from 3rd server, like perl, .NET, java etc... Then the data you would push to your monitoring system.

Comment: This is very generic, do you know about specific example? Thanks.

Comment: Well, we have setup monitoring of ESXi and VC via SNMP[1], it was much easier :) Those tools can send traps by themselves, then you can forward them to your monitoring tool.

I don't know your monitoring tool, but there are opensource tools which can transform snmptraps into text - like snmptt[2].


[1] http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1013445
[2] http://snmptt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Could you change your answer with the links you provided. I don't really care how I get the notifications as long as I get them. Could you share more details on how you have setup the two pieces together?

Comment: If by VC you mean vCenter, that is not an option BTW.